# Can we cry out of sadness during prayer? Will my salah be valid?

Tags: salat

I'm going through very hard times and I am really sad.So sometimes during salah I cry and tears drop without making any sound. Is my prayer valid if I cry out of sadness ? Please note when I am crying, I am not crying out of fear of Allah. Its just out of sadness I am crying.

Comment: While in Salah, that is not the time to be thinking of your worldly issues so it may suggest lack of focus in the prayer. Try to develop total focus. However, does crying over worldly reason invalidate your salah? No. Not unless you are being unreasonable in your crying and uttering noises/words. Just a tear or two shed shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Al-Mughni](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=775&bk_no=15&flag=1), [Ibn Qudamah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qudamah) said that if one cries during prayer due to a worldly matter because one got overwhelmed and could not drive the tears away, then the prayer is valid.

Crying in a loud voice over a worldly matter invalidates the prayer according to the four major schools of jurisprudence. Crying due to the fear of Allah does not invalidate the prayer; rather, it is what the Prophet ﷺ used to do quite often, and it is a sign of strong faith:

> إِنَّمَا يُؤْمِنُ بِآيَاتِنَا الَّذِينَ إِذَا ذُكِّرُوا بِهَا خَرُّوا سُجَّدًا وَسَبَّحُوا بِحَمْدِ رَبِّهِمْ وَهُمْ لَا يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ
>
> Only those who believe in Our verses who, when they are reminded of them, fall down in prostration and exalt [Allah] with praise of their Lord, and they are not arrogant.
>
> <sub>— [Surat As-Sajdah 32:15](https://quran.com/32/15/)</sub>